# Comparing and validating objects

Tags: java

I have a setter that has two parameters like so

```j
 public void setStuff(OBJECT x, OBJECT, y)
```

If the value of the x is greater than the y I want to set the value of x to BLAH_BLAH and y to FINAL_THING. How would I do this since they are objects and all I know is to check if they are equal. with the equals method.

Comment: What does "greater than" mean if they are just objects?

Comment: well I am following specifications and thats why I was confused because they are objects

Comment: Your question isn't well formed. In general, objects have no sense of ordering.

Comment: before this I checked if they were null and set them to values, then I am supposed to check for consistency

Comment: How can you set a value?  Do the classes extend (or implement) a class which defines how to get/set?  If so, you can cast.

Comment: Do you have a specification for 'OBJECT"?  Is thee some method in it that returns a value which makes sense for a comparison?

Comment: An object is an abstraction over data.  This means that an object can be written to represent, well, just about anything.  Because an object can be anything, the only facility that can define what "objectX greater than objectY" means (or, indeed, if it even makes sense to say) is the programmer of the objects.  Without knowing what the objects represent, there is no way to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to get the values of x and the value of y, then do this: 
pseudo java:

```
if (getValue of x > getValue of y),
x.setValue = xyz,
y.setValue = abc.
```

Answer (score 1):

For comparing objects I would suggest you to override equals method and in equals compare on the variable
This is a simple class CompareObject

```
public class CompareObjects {
public  int age;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    CompareObjects co=new CompareObjects();
    co.age=10;
    CompareObjects co1=new CompareObjects();
co1.age=100;
System.out.println(co.equals(co1));
}
public boolean equals(CompareObjects co)
{
    if(this.age>co.age)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
}
```

**output** false

Now you know which object is greater than which object.
Now you use this method in your `public void setStuff(OBJECT x, OBJECT, y)`

For example

```
public void setStuff(OBJECT x, OBJECT, y)
{
if(x.equals(y)
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something
}
}
```